# None of log files contains offset SCN: 9483418337736, re-snapshot is required

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am deploying a Debezium connector for oracle. When I deploy the connect it takes a consistent snapshot and it captures all the records being inserted into the table. After a while ranging from a few minutes to hours, it fails complaining about the SCN could not be found. When I perform a fresh snapshot it starts working and then fails after a while with the same error.

Following is the deployed config.

```json
{
    "name": "debezium-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
        "message.key.columns": "COMMON.SETTLEMENT_DAY:SETTLEMENT_DAY",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "debezium.schema-changes.inventory",
        "log.mining.strategy": "online_catalog",
        "signal.data.collection": "ABC.debezium_signal",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "log.mining.archive.log.hours": "2",
        "database.user": "ABC",
        "database.dbname": "EDPM",
        "database.connection.adapter": "logminer",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "10.0.0.36:9092,10.0.0.37:9092,10.0.0.38:9092",
        "database.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/EDPM",
        "time.precision.mode": "connect",
        "database.server.name": "DEBEZIUM",
        "event.processing.failure.handling.mode": "warn",
        "heartbeat.interval.ms": "300000",
        "database.port": "1521",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "database.hostname": "localhost",
        "database.password": "************",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "name": "debezium-connector",
        "table.include.list": "COMMON.SETTLEMENT_DAY,ABC.debezium_signal",
        "snapshot.mode": "schema_only"
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```json
{
    "name": "debezium-connector",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "0.0.0.0:28084"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "FAILED",
            "worker_id": "0.0.0.0:28084",
            "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.\n\tat
io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:42)\n\tat
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:211)\n\tat
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:63)\n\tat
io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:159)\n\tat 
io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:122)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: None of log files contains offset SCN: 9483418337736, re-snapshot is required.\n\tat 
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerHelper.setLogFilesForMining(LogMinerHelper.java:480)\n\tat 
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.initializeRedoLogsForMining(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:248)\n\tat 
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:167)\n\t... 8 more\n"
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

Comment: Please follow the link below for more insight on the issue.  https://debezium.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/302529-users/topic/logminer